# saving json files into one single csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have 100s of similar json files and I want to save the contents of these json files into one single csv file. This is the code I wrote for the same. But it's not doing what I want to do.
Desired output is csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cgwdbnvETLf6nO1tNnH0F_-fLxUOdT7L/view?usp=sharing

Please tell me what can be done to get the above output? Thanks
JSON file format: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-OZYrfUtDJmwcRUjpBgn59zJt5MjtmWt/view?usp=sharing

```
list_=['politifact13565', 'politifact13601'] 
for i in list_:
    with open("{}/news content.json".format(i)) as json_input:
        json_data = json.load(json_input, strict=False)
        mydict = {}
        mydict["url"] = json_data["url"]
        mydict["text"] = json_data["text"]
        mydict["images"]=json_data["images"]
        mydict["title"]=json_data["title"]
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')
        df = df.T
        df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_csv('out.csv')
        print(df)
```

SOLVED:

```
list_=['politifact13565', 'politifact13601'] 
for i in list_:
    with open("{}/news content.json".format(i)) as json_input:
        json_data = json.load(json_input, strict=False)
        mydict = {}
        mydict["url"] = json_data["url"]
        mydict["text"] = json_data["text"]
        mydict["images"]=json_data["images"]
        mydict["title"]=json_data["title"]
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')
        df = df.T
        df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', header=False)
        print(df)
```

Comment: Please post a example of one of those jsons so we can copy and try on our own. Screenshots are not so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_=['politifact13565', 'politifact13601'] 
for i in list_:
    with open("{}/news content.json".format(i)) as json_input:
        json_data = json.load(json_input, strict=False)
        mydict = {}
        mydict["url"] = json_data["url"]
        mydict["text"] = json_data["text"]
        mydict["images"]=json_data["images"]
        mydict["title"]=json_data["title"]
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index')
        df = df.T
        df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', header=False)
        print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is quite close to the desired output, you just need to [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the imported json:

```
import glob
directory = "your/path/to/jsons/*.json"
df = pd.concat([pd.read_json(f, orient="index").T for f in glob.glob(directory)], ignore_index=True)
```

Aferwards you can save the df using `df.to_csv("tweets.csv")` 
Hopefully that helps you!

Comment: Error: nothing to concatenate

Comment: Problem solved- I have Updated the solution. Thanks for helping @Andre S.