# Convert multiple json files into a single csv file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have thousands of json files that I need to combine into a single csv file. Sample json file: https://www.codepile.net/pile/dZGybzwy

I am trying to use a python script to do this since I will be having the sets of json files saved in separate folders with this structure: /Saved/09_24_2020_15_05_5_Town03/targets, /Saved/09_22_2020_15_58_8_Town03/targets, etc. (the json files are located in the target folder) and would like to use a flag to select which folder I need the json files from.

I referred to the similar questions that were already asked here such as [saving json files into one single csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587587/saving-json-files-into-one-single-csv) and [Convert multiple .txt files into single .csv file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532578/convert-multiple-txt-files-into-single-csv-file-python) but the issue I'm having is the .csv file that is created does not have any of the contents of the json files. I would also like the csv file to have the same name as the parent folder in Saved e.g. 09_24_2020_15_05_5_Town03.csv

This is the code I've written:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import argparse
import os
import os.path

from carlahelp.filehelp import read_json

df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir('Saved/'):
    if file.endswith('.json'):
        frame=pd.read_json(...)
        df = df.append(frame, ignore_index=True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    data_dir = 'Saved/'
    all_recordings = os.listdir(data_dir)
    if len(all_recordings)==0:
        print("No recordings found in Saved/ folder")
        exit()

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    #default to latest recording if none specified
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--recording', type=str, default=all_recordings[-1])
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("Saving to csv {} from {}")
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(data_dir,args.recording+'.csv'))
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18. Would greatly appreciate any help and advice :) Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that the data you want is present in `df` before you try to save it as a `.csv`? By printing `df.head()`, for instance?

Comment: Just a note on `os.listdir()`, from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.listdir): *"The list is in arbitrary order."* So if you want to default to latest, you'd need to wrap that in a `sorted()` call.

Comment: @JamesTollefson I get "NameError: name 'df' is not defined" when printing df.head() or print(df)
Could you please help me figure out where my code is wrong?